# Does disconnected imply there are $A, B$ with $\overline{A} \cap \overline{B} = \emptyset$?

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X, \mathcal{T})$ be a topological space. Is the following equivalent to disconnectedness?

> There exist disjoint non-empty subsets $A, B \subseteq X$ such that $X = A \sqcup B$ and $\overline{A} \cap \overline{B} = \emptyset$.

If it isn't true in general, how about if we look specifically at $X = \mathbb{R}$ with the usual topology?

Note: $(X, \mathcal{T})$ is said to be disconnected if there exist disjoint non-empty subsets $A, B \subseteq X$ such that $X = A \sqcup B$ and $\overline{A} \cap B = \emptyset$ and $A \cap \overline{B} = \emptyset$.

**My attempt**: The stated property implies disconnectedness, because if $\overline{A} \cap \overline{B} = \emptyset$ are disjoint, then also $\overline{A} \cap B = \emptyset$ and $A \cap \overline{B} = \emptyset$.

As for the converse, I'm not sure; I suspect it isn't true, but I can't seem to produce an example of a disconnected set that doesn't have the stated property. I thought of simple examples like $X = (0,1) \sqcup (1,2)$ (as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}$), but I don't think this works (but I'm not sure).

Comment: What definition of connectedness (or disconnectedness) are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's true in general: for disconnected $X$ the sets $A,B$ can be  chosen disjoint, non-empty and closed, so $\overline{A}=A, \overline{B}=B$ and so your property is easy to see.

If we have a non-trivial partition by $X$ by separated subsets (as in your definition), the used sets are in fact closed and also open in $X$, as is easy to see. Many texts even define having a non-trivial clopen set as the definition of disconnectedness, or equivalently, a non-constant continuous function from $X$ to the discrete space $\{0,1\}$ etc.